# GameObject's Following a Leader / Centipede Issue

Tags: c#, gameobject, unity-game-engine

I am having difficulty chaining together some GameObjects to "Follow the leader".

This is what I am trying to accomplish:

[image]

Where there is a "head" object and it pulls the  `body` objects with it. Like a snake or centipede.

However, this is what is happening:

[image]

They all kinda follow the head and but they seem to move as a whole.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Here is my Centipede Object that the others classes inherit from.
I started to tinker with the idea of just making the CentipedeObject move all of the independent GameObjects. But that didn't work.

**CentipedeObject.cs**

```
public abstract class CentipedeObject : MonoBehaviour {

    [SerializeField]
    private float moveSpeed = 1.5f;

    public float MoveSpeed {
        get {
            return moveSpeed;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the **CentipedeHead** that does the moving.

```
public class CentipedeHead : CentipedeObject {

    private Rigidbody2D _body;
    private Vector2 moveDirection = Vector2.zero;
    private void Awake() {
        _body = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        _body.gravityScale = 0;
        _body.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints2D.FreezeRotation;

    }
    private void Start() {
        InvokeRepeating("ChangeDirection", 0, Random.Range(1.25f, 3.0f));
    }

    private void FixedUpdate() {
        _body.velocity = moveDirection.normalized * MoveSpeed;
    }

    private void ChangeDirection() {

        moveDirection = Vector2.zero;

        switch (Random.Range(0, 4)) {
            case 0:
                moveDirection += Vector2.up;
                break;
            case 1:
                moveDirection += Vector2.right;
                break;
            case 2:
                moveDirection += Vector2.down;
                break;
            case 3:
                moveDirection += Vector2.left;
                break;

        }
    }
}
```

And the **CentipedeBody** part that should just follow the head *or* another body part.

```
public class CentipedeBody : CentipedeObject {

    public GameObject objectToFollow;

    private Vector3 followSize;

    void Start() {
        //Get the size of the object we are following
        followSize = objectToFollow.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().bounds.size;

        //Set initial distance
        transform.position = objectToFollow.transform.position + followSize;
    }

    private void FixedUpdate() {
        Vector3 followFromPosition = objectToFollow.transform.position + followSize;
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, followFromPosition, MoveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: Keyword is *following*, something should repeat someone else path.

Comment: When the head (1) moves to a new spot, the first body piece (2) should move to where the head just was, then piece (3) should move to where piece (2) just was, then (4) to (3) and so on... Work out the logic to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I think the logic of updating the pixels is wrong. When the head moves one pixel left. You are making all other body parts move left by 1 pixel. Where as what you need to do is that (from your diagram) 2 takes the exact place where 1 was. 3 takes the place where 2 was and so on.